# ctype_alpha returns false when wrapped inside a function with parameter

Tags: php

I have a simple function that looks like this:

```
public function validate_alpha_numeric($string_param) {
    return ctype_alpha($string_param);
}
```

When running this function...

```
var_dump($validation->validate_alpha_numeric("Hello World"));
```

...it always returns false. I've var_dumped the $string_param parameter inside the function, and it returns a string. But for some reason, ctype_alpha doesn't think so.

Any idea why this function returns false, even when the parameter is an alphanumeric string?

Comment: `ctype_alpha` doesn't allow spaces.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space is not considered an alphanumeric character.

See [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php):

> In the standard C locale letters are just [A-Za-z] and ctype_alpha() is equivalent to (ctype_upper($text) || ctype_lower($text)).